# play local swf on android

Tags: html, animation, flash

I tried to play a local swf on html file. but it doesnt work. I use Android ICS. The html file doesnt show the swf file. Anyone can help me?
This is my html code. I already put my swf into sdcard.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <object width="275" height="235">
      <param name="movie" value="48cd_Crossbed_SP.swf">
        <embed src="file:///mnt/sdcard/48cd_Crossbed_SP.swf"
               width="235" height="200">
        </embed>
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried make my swf and my html in one folder too with this code below. But it still not working.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <object width="275" height="235">
      <param name="movie" value="48cd_Crossbed_SP.swf">
        <embed src="48cd_Crossbed_SP.swf"
               width="235" height="200">
        </embed>
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have Flash installed on the device? Flash is deprecated (though still installable via side-loading) in Android, and not available on many devices anymore.

Comment: If you move the HTML page and the SWF file to another device, like a desktop computer with Flash, does it open and work there?

Answer (score 0):

Flash won't show on many mobile devices now as it uses too much resources. You should take a look at a JQuery/Javascript alternative. If you don't know much Javascript then check out some tutorials or you could pay for a browser in the marketplace which has Flash enabled although if you're expecting others to view this flash on a mobile device then I wouldn't hold your breath as many won't pay for a browser just to view flash on a site.

Comment: Oke, thankyou for your answer. I developed an android program wich showing swf animation. There is another way to resolve it? it is impossible if you suggest to convert it to video format .

Comment: What exactly is the SWF? If is a video then you could convert it into mp4 and ogg formats and use the new html5 video tags.If it's just a slideshow of images then you could use a JQuery plugin like cycle.js as you can no longer rely on everyone having Flash now and should find alternatives.